# Seeing size on disc of raster in file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, file-geodatabase, arccatalog

I am trying to determine the size of the individual raster layers that I have within a file geodatabase while viewing the GDB in ArcCatalog. I have enabled the size column, but that only displays the size for feature classes. I can find out the size of each by checking each one's properties, but I'm looking for a more efficient way of seeing all of their sizes.

Comment: Table size is nearly impossible to determine without creating a new FGDB, getting the size, adding the raster, then getting the size again. It's probably easier to just use a mosaic dataset; then you'll at least know the file and pyramid sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/best-way-to-get-size-on-disk-of-raster/td-p/373519

I think you can use ArcPy to get the raster pixel area using the [Get Raster Properties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-raster-properties.htm) tool, then multiply by the byte size and multiply again by the number of layers.